# JPA Eclipselink - Trigger SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, jpa, trigger, eclipse-link

Estou tendo um problema com relação a uma trigger criada no SQL SERVER.
Quando insiro os dados na tabela que starta a trigger direto no SQL SERVER a trigger funciona normal, entretanto quando realizado a inserção pelo JPA ele apresenta um erro e da rollback.

Segue o erro:

```
[EL Warning]: 2016-06-18 12:29:39.144--UnitOfWork(2039736611)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Um conjunto de resultados foi gerado para atualização.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO EMPRESTIMO (DATAEMPRESTIMO, EMPRESTIMOMAISTAXA, LIMITEPARCELA, NUMEROPARCELA, NUMEROPARCELAMINIMA, PARCELAMAXIMA, PRIMEIRAPARCELA, SALARIOLIQUIDO, TAXAJUROS, VALOREMPRESTIMO, VALORJUROS, VALORPARCELA, CLIENTE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [13 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(JPA.EmprestimoPOJO@64d8f425)
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Um conjunto de resultados foi gerado para atualização.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO EMPRESTIMO (DATAEMPRESTIMO, EMPRESTIMOMAISTAXA, LIMITEPARCELA, NUMEROPARCELA, NUMEROPARCELAMINIMA, PARCELAMAXIMA, PRIMEIRAPARCELA, SALARIOLIQUIDO, TAXAJUROS, VALOREMPRESTIMO, VALORJUROS, VALORPARCELA, CLIENTE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [13 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(JPA.EmprestimoPOJO@64d8f425)
Erro ao gravar no banco de dados
```

TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_PARCELAS 
ON EMPRESTIMO
AFTER INSERT

AS

    --valor a serem inseridos na inserted

    DECLARE @PG         BIT
    DECLARE @VLR        FLOAT
    DECLARE @VCM        DATE
    DECLARE @IDEMPR     INT
    DECLARE @NPARCELA   INT
    DECLARE @AUX        INT

BEGIN

    --Pega valores da linha inserida de emprestimo
    SELECT  @VLR = VALORPARCELA, @VCM = PRIMEIRAPARCELA, @IDEMPR = ID, @NPARCELA = NUMEROPARCELA
    FROM INSERTED

    --Set AUX como 0
    SET @AUX = 0
    SET @PG = 0

    WHILE @AUX < @NPARCELA BEGIN

        Select DateAdd(month, @AUX, @VCM)
        INSERT INTO PARCELA (PAGO, VALOR, VENCIMENTO, EMPRESTIMO_ID) 
        VALUES (0, @VLR, @VCM, @IDEMPR)

        SET @AUX = @AUX + 1

        END

END
```

Alguem ja teve o mesmo problema?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas por essa linha do erro ´´Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Um conjunto de resultados foi gerado para atualização.´´ Tenta substituir os ´´select's´´ da trigger por ´´set´´.

Answer (score 0):

O problema estava na seguinte linha que realizava select dentro do loop.

```
Select DateAdd(month, @AUX, @VCM)
```

O SQL SERVER acabou se complicando com o tratamento dos diversos retornos que teve desse select. Assim que eu tirei funcionou normalmente.